# How to set multiple column not equal to zero in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Is there any way in the **mysql/oracle** where you can set **mulitiple column != 0**

I have 10+ columns in the table and I want **select those column which has value != 0**

One way is to use **AND** as many times as those number of columns in the table .

The exaple is :

```
    SELECT `id`, `user_name`, `reference_id`, `adventure`, `beach`, `culture`,
   `festival`, `food`, `fun`, `biking`, `ski`, `surf`, `family`, `couple`,
   `single` FROM `ratings` 
    WHERE `adventure`!=0 
    AND `beach`!=0 
    AND `culture`!=0
    AND `festival`!=0
    AND `food`!=0
    AND `fun`!=0
    AND `biking`!=0
    AND `ski`!=0
    AND  `surf`!=0
    AND `family`!=0
    AND `couple`!=0
    AND `single`!=0
```

Is there any better way to do this **instead of adding those many AND/OR**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why - vote down! please explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT `id`, `user_name`, ...
FROM `ratings` 
WHERE 0 NOT IN (`adventure`, `beach`, `culture`, `festival`, ...)
```

Comment: Ah..beat me to it...was just about to post it

Comment: Just wondering if there is some performance difference between these two syntaxes?

Comment: It's working for AND I want for OR(Multiple or conditions) how to do that?

Comment: @sandip - Use `WHERE 0 IN (festival, fun, food)` instead.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal awesome! Thanks. May I know why people down voted my quetion? I mean is it wrong question

Comment: @sandip - You're welcome any time, I don't know really why they down voted your question. Your question is clear and useful, but it is happens all the time here. Sorry for that.

Comment: @coramba - I don't know really, but as far as I know the predicate `IN` is faster than multiple `OR`s, there is a post about that here in Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find it.